# How to display Image from camera roll url using react-native-camera?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I use react-native-camera for capturing images and saving them in cameraRoll (CaptureTarget) for iOS devices, on capture I get image path in the following form

```
"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=8B55D3E5-11CE-439A-8FC6-D55EB1A88D7E&ext=JPG"
```

How to use this path to display the image in Image component (from react-native)?

Previously I was using disk as CaptureTarget option, and I was able to show that image url Image component but now the requirements are to save image in camera roll?

Comment: did you work this out at all ?

Comment: @ajonno please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

I have used RNFetchBlob to get base64 from "assets-library://.." url, my capture function is

```
this.camera.capture()
      .then((data) => {
        // console.log(data);
        RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(data.path, 'base64')
          .then((base64data) => {
            let base64Image = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64data}`;
            this.props.addImagesToUntagged(data.path);
          })

      })
```

after that i give user some in-app functionality on this base64 data and finally when I need to send this to s3 server, I use axios & RNFetchBlob to send this data.following code gives me signed url for s3

```
axios.get(ENDPOINT_TO_GET_SIGNED_URL, {params:{'file-name': file.name,'file-type': file.type,"content-type": 'evidence'}})
  .then(function (result) {
    //  console.log(result);
    returnUrl = result.data.url;
    var signedUrl = result.data.signedRequest;
    return uploadFile(file,signedUrl)
  })
```

and in my uploadFile function i upload images through following code

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch('PUT', signedUrl,
    {'Content-Type' : file.type},
    RNFetchBlob.wrap(file.uri)
  )
  .then(resolve)
```